# My rails console showing garbage output after I enter any wrong command

Tags: ruby-on-rails, command-line-arguments, rails-console

If I type any wrong command, then my rails console is going crazy and taking random command and showing that commands output, instead of showing the exact one. But if I reopen it, then it works fine. So every time I have to reopen the console and retype from the beginning.

**for example**: If I type any wrong command and in the next try, if I type **up key** then it is showing " **[** ", instead of showing previous command.

Sometimes it may happen that, if I type backspace then it deletes everything on the screen(i.e. Desktop/User> this too).

Is there any solution??

Comment: Does this only happen in a rails console? What if you try `irb`, the ruby console?

Comment: It is happening with only rails console. irb is working fine.

Comment: try to reload `reload!`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried many things, but finally updated rails(temporary fix). Worked fine.
Answering this after many days, as the other people who will come across this will get idea about temporary fix.